# Creating a list of strings with varying subscripts

Tags: python-2.7

I want to define a function which takes input a value m and returns a vector C=['c1','c2',...,'cm']. How do I vary the subscript or the index of the strings inside the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This should work](https://repl.it/@DoloMike/FamiliarFriendlyProfiler):

```
def makeList(m):
    return ['c' + str(x+1) for x in xrange(m)]

newList = makeList(5)
print(newList)
```

The function takes an argument `m` and uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build a list of strings with length `m`. You could of course change `'c'` to any other string you want to prepend to the integer.